# align variable length function arguments with clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

I relatively often come across code like this

```
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_RANDOM",&Regression_Q2_RANDOM,"Regression_Q2_RANDOM/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_BEST",&Regression_Q2_BEST,"Regression_Q2_BEST/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_WORST",&Regression_Q2_WORST,"Regression_Q2_WORST/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_TRUE",&Regression_Q2_TRUE,"Regression_Q2_TRUE/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_HI",&Regression_Q2_HI,"Regression_Q2_HI/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_LO",&Regression_Q2_LO,"Regression_Q2_LO/F");
```

Most auto formaters are anyhow not happy with this due to the long lines, but that aside, I would like to have the function arguments aligned like this:

```
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_RANDOM",&Regression_Q2_RANDOM,"Regression_Q2_RANDOM/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_BEST",  &Regression_Q2_BEST,  "Regression_Q2_BEST/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_WORST", &Regression_Q2_WORST, "Regression_Q2_WORST/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_TRUE",  &Regression_Q2_TRUE,  "Regression_Q2_TRUE/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_HI",    &Regression_Q2_HI,    "Regression_Q2_HI/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_LO",    &Regression_Q2_LO,    "Regression_Q2_LO/F");
```

such that with block editing I could replace the ampersands by asterisks, or do other block-manipulations to the common parts of the arguments. Can `clang-format` (or maybe another formater) do that?

BONUS POINTS:

This is probably too much to ask, but at best also the common ends of the strings should align:

```
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_RANDOM",&Regression_Q2_RANDOM,"Regression_Q2_RANDOM" "/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_BEST",  &Regression_Q2_BEST,  "Regression_Q2_BEST"   "/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_WORST", &Regression_Q2_WORST, "Regression_Q2_WORST"  "/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_TRUE",  &Regression_Q2_TRUE,  "Regression_Q2_TRUE"   "/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_HI",    &Regression_Q2_HI,    "Regression_Q2_HI"     "/F");
  tree->Branch("Regression_Q2_LO",    &Regression_Q2_LO,    "Regression_Q2_LO"     "/F");
```

Comment: iam not aware of this functionality in clang-format. especially the second one not in my experience. clang format splits strings on lines, but i never saw this. BUT it can align trailing comments, so maybe i just dont know it. i would like to have such alignment as well :)